# Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error

Tags: sql, r, sql-update, rsqlite

The following line of code:

```
sqldf("UPDATE q1_sql_1 SET MONTH_YEAR = RIGHT(MONTH_YEAR, LEN(MONTH_YEAR) - 4)")
```

Shows this error:

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: Use `RIGHTSTR` instead of `RIGHT`.

Comment: However I don't get why the error message is `syntax error`, it should be `no such function: RIGHT`. That's strange.

Comment: Only half of it is a duplicate. There are actually two errors in the sql statement. See my answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I agree. Do you have any idea why `select right('abc', 2)` reports a syntax error instead of an unknown function?

Comment: sqlite produces a syntax error even without R.

Comment: Yes. I guess it's because of the ambiguity with the `right` of `right join`.

Comment: Maybe but sqlite does not support right join.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: In case you're interested, I've asked and it turns out it's indeed because of the ambiguity with the `RIGHT` keyword. http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Improper-error-message-td100720.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `length` and `rightstr`.  For the functions available in SQLite see:

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

and for the contributed functions that RSQLite also makes available:

https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#example-15-use-of-rsqliteextfuns-library-functions